# Can new-chapter page break be omitted?

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, master-page

How do you start new chapters on the same page? I'm using the latest InDesign.

**EDIT:**

I'm making a book, with about a hundred short chapters, sometimes as short as half a page.

So far, I haven't made any decisions about how to structure this inside InDesign. This is intentional, so that I'll be able to implement the best answer to this question without hassle.

Comment: Welcome! Yes, you can remove pagebreaks, but it also depends how you inserted your text and how you built your stylesheet/masters. What exactly is your issue and what have your tried so far that didn't work? Your question could contain a bit more details!

Comment: What do you mean by “new chapters”? How are you starting your chapters? If you're just talking about a particular paragraph style that you're using as the header of your chapters, then yes, of course you can. If you're talking about individual documents in a Book, then no, you can't. If you're talking about the section numbering function, that is defined per page, so you can't start a new section in the middle of a page, for instance. It's not clear which (if any) of these you're referring to, though.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks, I just edited the question with more context.

Comment: @go-meek I haven't made any such decisions yet, intentionally. See my edit to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your edit, the answer is **yes**, it is possible to start a new chapter in a book without having a page break before it.

InDesign does have an actual chapter feature, but that is directly related to individual documents in an InDesign Book (a special type of InDesign file that contains references to a list of individual InDesign documents that each represent a chapter to appear in the final work). Using the Book feature, it is not possible to start a new document/chapter on the same page as the previous one ends.

You can make books without using Books, however (note capitalisation). A single InDesign document can easily—and frequently does—represent an entire book. All the chapters in the book are then simply strings of text within that document, and what separates them—visually, the chapter title—is merely a particular paragraph style. Whether or not this paragraph style is set up to always begin on a new page (or, as is often the case in books with longer chapters, on the next right-side page) is up to you: you define the style, after all, so you can decide whether to set it up like this or not.

If you don’t set up your chapter title paragraph style to force a page break before it, it will simply appear at the place in the text flow where it is structurally: right after the end of the body text of the previous chapter.

If you plan on using the Sections and Numbering features, however, you should be aware that all options there are applied to an entire *page*, so if you have two half-page chapters on the same page, you’ll have to choose which one should be used as far as Sections and Numbering is concerned. But that’s a practical caveat you’d have had to worry about anyway: if you have running headers along the top of each page, for instance, you would in any case have to decide which of the two half-page chapters that both appear on page 48 would give their title to the running header, whether InDesign’s Section features forced you to or not.

Comment: Thanks. I was concerned that I couldn't use the Book & Chapter features with chapters that don't have page breaks. I assume the downside is that it's a lot harder to automatically apply master styles to different parts of the chapter when you just use a single document for a whole book, right?

Comment: @sdegutis You mean like having a specific type of master page with no page numbers for pages that start a new chapter, for example? Yes, that sort of thing is easier when each chapter is a separate document, because you can set it up as part of the document template.

Comment: Well, I don't know much about master pages yet, but I'd like to have a Chapter Title style, the First Paragraph style, the Normal Paragraph style, the New Section style (like the First Paragraph style but starts a new section with in a chapter), and two separate types of Conclusion styles, since each chapter always ends with two separate Conclusion paragraphs with different names. I don't know how much control master pages have over this much order-specific styling, either inside or outside the Book & Chapter feature.

Comment: Neither master pages nor Book features make any difference for that: you always apply the style to the paragraphs you want it applied to manually anyways. You can specify what style the _next_ paragraph should have, too, which can make things easier—if you set this up right (and need just one of each in a row), you can highlight quite a few paragraphs of text and then apply the desired style + following styles, and it will all look the way it's meant to. You'll have to do it individually for each chapter, though, if there aren't already styles applied in the text.

Comment: Great. Since I'll be importing content via XML, I don't think doing it manually will be a necessary. I'm pretty sure importing content via XML allows you to apply styles to any node within the XML document, even nodes within nodes (styling nested content). So with that, I suspect I won't need the "Next Paragraph" feature.

Comment: Absolutely. If it's XML, you'll be fine—apart, of course, from the fact that handling XML is probably the most infuriatingly confusing and unintuitive thing you can do in InDesign to begin with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30592/discussion-between-sdegutis-and-janus-bahs-jacquet).